# Add dynamic HTML Classes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a HTML Page that creates more or less dynamic iframes. It works perfect but the only problem is that I have no idea how to add (only with Javascript) the `class="active"` - without changing the html code? What I want is that the active link is highlited.

One possibility I have is to add an ID to every `li` and to use `document.getElementById(ID).classList.add("active");`.

```css
html,
  body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
   font-size: 12px;
  }
  
  #logo {
   position: absolute;
   top: 40px;
   left: 40px;
   width: 180px;
   height: 38px;
  }
  
  h1 {
   position: absolute;
   font-family: "Monserat";
   font-size: 28px;
   color: #444;
   top: 40px;
   right: 40px;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  
  #navigation {
   position: absolute;
   top: 120px;
   left: 40px;
   width: calc(100% - 80px);
  }
  
  #content {
   position: absolute;
   width: calc(100% - 80px);
   bottom: 40px;
   left: 40px;
   text-align: center;
  }
  
  ul,
  li {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
   display: inline-block;
   margin-right: 20px;
  }
  
  li {
   cursor: pointer;
   font-size: 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #999;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  
  hr {
   border: 0;
   height: 1px;
   background: #999;
  }
  
  iframe {
   width: 160px;
   height: 600px;
   border: 0;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  li:hover,
  .active {
   color: #333;
  }
```

```html
<body>
 <img src="images/logo.svg" id="logo" class="logo">
 <h1 id="headline" class="headline"></h1>
 <div id="navigation" class="navigation">
  <ul>
   <li onclick="adformat(160,600,'motiv')">160x600</li>
   <li onclick="adformat(300,250,'topic')">300x250</li>
   <li onclick="adformat(300,600,'topic')">300x600</li>
   <li onclick="adformat(600,300,'topic')">600x300</li>
   <li onclick="adformat(728,90,'topic')">728x90</li>
   <li onclick="adformat(800,250,'topic')">800x250</li>
   <li onclick="adformat(970,250,'topic')">970x250</li>
  </ul>
  <hr>
 </div>
 <div id="content" class="content">
  <div id="project01" class="project01"><iframe src="" id="view" class="view"></iframe></div>
 </div>

</body>
<script>
 setSize();

 window.addEventListener("resize", setSize);

 function setSize() {
  var navihoehe = document.getElementById("navigation").offsetHeight;
  var navihoehekomplett = navihoehe + 174;
  document.getElementById("content").style.height = "calc(100% - " + navihoehekomplett + "px)";
 }

 document.getElementById("headline").innerHTML = "Campaign 2017";

 document.getElementById("view").style.width = "0";
 document.getElementById("view").style.height = "0";

 function adformat(adBreite, adHoehe, adMotiv) {
  iframeLink = adBreite + "x" + adHoehe + "_" + adMotiv + "/index.html";
  document.getElementById("view").src = iframeLink;
  document.getElementById("view").style.width = adBreite + "px";
  document.getElementById("view").style.height = adHoehe + "px";
 }
</script>
```

Comment: can you provide fiddle for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with `id` .try with `tagname` or `classname` . [`querySelectorAll('ul li')`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjvoNmM3ezUAhXDMo8KHdSeDQgQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FDocument%2FquerySelectorAll&usg=AFQjCNGw4XxpSz-PKB1SUB1yNenuYzkpUw) use to find the respected element .ForEach used to iterate the element one by one

**Updated**

1. li click event
2. highlight only the selected element

**with remove class**

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('ul li').forEach(function(a) {
    a.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelectorAll('ul li').forEach(function(b){
    b.classList.remove("active");
    })
      this.classList.add("active")
    })
  })
}
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('ul li').forEach(function(a) {

    a.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelectorAll('ul li').forEach(function(b){
    b.classList.remove("active");
    })
      this.classList.add("active")
    })
  })
}
setSize();

window.addEventListener("resize", setSize);

function setSize() {
  var navihoehe = document.getElementById("navigation").offsetHeight;
  var navihoehekomplett = navihoehe + 174;
  document.getElementById("content").style.height = "calc(100% - " + navihoehekomplett + "px)";
}

document.getElementById("headline").innerHTML = "Campaign 2017";

document.getElementById("view").style.width = "0";
document.getElementById("view").style.height = "0";

function adformat(adBreite, adHoehe, adMotiv) {
  iframeLink = adBreite + "x" + adHoehe + "_" + adMotiv + "/index.html";
  document.getElementById("view").src = iframeLink;
  document.getElementById("view").style.width = adBreite + "px";
  document.getElementById("view").style.height = adHoehe + "px";
  //console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("LI"));
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 38px;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Monserat";
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #444;
  top: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#navigation {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 40px;
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
  bottom: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

li {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

hr {
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background: #999;
}

iframe {
  width: 160px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li:hover,
.active {
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <img src="images/logo.svg" id="logo" class="logo">
  <h1 id="headline" class="headline"></h1>
  <div id="navigation" class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li onclick="adformat(160,600,'motiv')">160x600</li>
      <li onclick="adformat(300,250,'topic')">300x250</li>
      <li onclick="adformat(300,600,'topic')">300x600</li>
      <li onclick="adformat(600,300,'topic')">600x300</li>
      <li onclick="adformat(728,90,'topic')">728x90</li>
      <li onclick="adformat(800,250,'topic')">800x250</li>
      <li onclick="adformat(970,250,'topic')">970x250</li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div id="content" class="content">
    <div id="project01" class="project01"><iframe src="" id="view" class="view"></iframe></div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: It should be added by click on "li".

Comment: @SebastianKullas the solution you have chosen won't remove the active state from others li elements. If a link is active it will stay always active unless you click it again, this is totally wrong

Comment: Thanks, for your help!

Comment: @chsdk ..Thanks for your valuable comment :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the clicked `li` in the onclick handler using `this` keyword and toggle the `active class accordingly:

**HTML**

```
    <ul>
      <li onclick="adformat(160,600,'motiv', this)">160x600</li>
      <li onclick="adformat(300,250,'topic', this)">300x250</li>
      <li onclick="adformat(300,600,'topic', this )">300x600</li>
      <li onclick="adformat(600,300,'topic', this)">600x300</li>
      <li onclick="adformat(728,90,'topic', this)">728x90</li>
      <li onclick="adformat(800,250,'topic', this)">800x250</li>
      <li onclick="adformat(970,250,'topic', this)">970x250</li>
    </ul>
```

**JS:**

```
  function adformat(adBreite, adHoehe, adMotiv, li) {
    li.classList.add('active');
    var others = document.querySelectorAll("ul li");
    for (var i = 0; i < others.length; i++) {
      if (others[i] != li) {
        others[i].classList.remove('active');
      }
    }
    iframeLink = adBreite + "x" + adHoehe + "_" + adMotiv + "/index.html";
    document.getElementById("view").src = iframeLink;
    document.getElementById("view").style.width = adBreite + "px";
    document.getElementById("view").style.height = adHoehe + "px";
  }
```

**Demo:**

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 38px;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Monserat";
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #444;
  top: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#navigation {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 40px;
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
  bottom: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

li {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

hr {
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background: #999;
}

iframe {
  width: 160px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li:hover,
.active {
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <img src="images/logo.svg" id="logo" class="logo">
  <h1 id="headline" class="headline"></h1>
  <div id="navigation" class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li onclick="adformat(160,600,'motiv', this)">160x600</li>
      <li onclick="adformat(300,250,'topic', this)">300x250</li>
      <li onclick="adformat(300,600,'topic', this )">300x600</li>
      <li onclick="adformat(600,300,'topic', this)">600x300</li>
      <li onclick="adformat(728,90,'topic', this)">728x90</li>
      <li onclick="adformat(800,250,'topic', this)">800x250</li>
      <li onclick="adformat(970,250,'topic', this)">970x250</li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div id="content" class="content">
    <div id="project01" class="project01"><iframe src="" id="view" class="view"></iframe></div>
  </div>

</body>
<script>
  setSize();

  window.addEventListener("resize", setSize);

  function setSize() {
    var navihoehe = document.getElementById("navigation").offsetHeight;
    var navihoehekomplett = navihoehe + 174;
    document.getElementById("content").style.height = "calc(100% - " + navihoehekomplett + "px)";
  }

  document.getElementById("headline").innerHTML = "Campaign 2017";

  document.getElementById("view").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("view").style.height = "0";

  function adformat(adBreite, adHoehe, adMotiv, li) {
    li.classList.add('active');
    var others = document.querySelectorAll("ul li");
    for (var i = 0; i < others.length; i++) {
      if (others[i] != li) {
        others[i].classList.remove('active');
      }
    }
    iframeLink = adBreite + "x" + adHoehe + "_" + adMotiv + "/index.html";
    document.getElementById("view").src = iframeLink;
    document.getElementById("view").style.width = adBreite + "px";
    document.getElementById("view").style.height = adHoehe + "px";
  }
</script>
```